# size of variable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I would like to know how much memory is being occupied by a variable.

Let us assume this example:

```
import numpy as np

t = [np.random.rand(10000) for _ in range(1000)]
```

How much memory in megabytes is `t` occupying?

I ran:

`sys.getsizeof(array_list)`

and I am getting `8856` which seems low for the amount of information contained in `t`

Best Regards.

Comment: This is a lot harder to pin down in languages like Python than, say, C. Are you counting the overhead of the array?

Comment: @tadman should be the size of everything. I am using `sys.getsizeof(t)` but it is giving me 8856 bytes... which seems too low

Comment: That could be the size of the array, excluding the size of the values. In other words, also count the `getsizeof(e)` for each element `e`.

Comment: Yeah, getsizeof is telling you the size of the list, not its contained objects.

Comment: I would like the size of everything. How much memory am I alocating to store that array

Comment: In this simple case, you could sum the getsizeof of the contents of the list (plus the list itself). `sum(sys.getsizeof(v) for v in t) + getsizeof(t)`. But the linked question above has more options.

Comment: you made a `list`, not an array.  Lists contain pointers/references, so `getsizeof` is a poor measure.  For numeric dtype arrays, `nbytes` and `getsizeof` are in good agreement.

Comment: For lists and dict total memory use has to take into account space used by the referenced elements, which can get very complicated.  A list may have repeated references to the same object, ints of various sizes, floats, strings, and who knows what else.  In comparison memory use of numeric dtype arrays is simple - if you take time to learn numpy basics.

Comment: A list of 1000 arrays, each with `10000` element floats - nbytes `of 10000*8, about 80000.  So roughly 1000*8 for list references plus 1000*80000. for content.  Here contents dominates to total memory use.  80Mb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from pympler import asizeof
asizeof.asizeof([np.random.rand(10000) for _ in range(1000)])

#output
80120872
```

Link : https://pypi.org/project/Pympler/

```
pip install Pympler
```

Comment: I have tried this one. It works the best for list of multidimensional arrays. [Although it is an external library]